# Jquery Draggable Placeholder

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I want to have a placeholder to be displayed when i drag items into the droppable container as like the placeholder displayed in JQuery Sortable.

We have a placeholder option in JQuery sortable. Is there anything similar to this in JQuery draggable method or anyway how can i make that.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Hi raja, do you need any highlighter for the draggable item during drag.?

Comment: @sathish i need to highlight the location where the item is to be dropped.

Comment: Did you find any results for this? I need something similar...

Answer (score 1):

try below code,

As you mentioned, "container will have many elements". I assume those container will have  'div' elements.

```
$("#container_drop div").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
    },
    over: function (event, ui) {
        $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
    },
    out: function (event, ui) {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
    }
});
```

Comment: @ sathish Thanks for your suggestion i was doing the samething in drag option in draggable method already. It doesn't work as expected. let me try changing some css as the highlight falls in some place but the item is dropped in some other location

Comment: @Raja there is a parameter available "hoverClass" for droppable.. u can try this also..

Comment: @Raja the above method is for droppable and not for draggable.

Comment: i was using similar method in draggable. i just want to make it simpler as like the sortable placeholder. so i was looking around.

Answer (score 0):

Try the blow code,

```
$( "#container_drag" ).draggable({

      drag: function() {
        $('#container_drop').addClass('highlight_container');
      },
      stop: function() {
        $('#container_drop').removeClass('highlight_container');
      }

});
```

Where, container_drag - your draggable container and container_drop - where the items going to be dropped.

And in Css,

```
.highlight_container{border:...,background:...}
```

Comment: @ sathish Thanks for ur suggestion but from above code the whole container will be highlighted and not the particular point where the item is to be dropped. container will be containing many elements in that i may drop inbetween the elements

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your parent elements have IDs, here's some code from a recent project I did at work which worked for me:

```
$('#container').draggable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        $('#' + ui.helper.context.id).addClass('active');
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $('#' + ui.helper.context.id).removeClass('active');
    }
})
```

Even without an ID you can probably get it to work. Hope this helps :)